# How do I make a holder/transactions entity in Core Data?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

Lets say we have the entities: Participant, Rewards, RewardsRedeemed

A participant can perform tasks to earn rewards. Rewards is a table of all of the rewards available. Rewards Redeemed is a "transaction" table of sorts where it would store which participants redeemed what rewards.

That of course is the Database way. How do I translate this desired functionality of having a "transaction" entity into the Core Data model?

Comment: What options have you thought about? Have you tried sketching potential entities and relationships?

Comment: I made an Entity named "redeemedRewards". I also made relationships to it. But there are no attributes and something seems off. Since we don't deal with foreign keys there is no need for attributes here i would suppose

Comment: If you don't need additional attributes you don't need them.  That's fine.

Comment: I would have Participant and Rewards as 2 entities, and use a BOOL flag on Rewards to say if its Redeemed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in comment above, just use a flag for Redeemed.

I'm no core data pro, but something like this could work

[image]

Comment: What if multiple people can redeem this same reward. Imagine that an award can be redeemed infinitely by many people. So we only need one record for a specific reward - but we also need a place to store every Participant that has redeemed that specific reward. How do I do that?

Comment: make it <<--->> so many to many both directions.... BUT I would just do it as the picture shows, and for the rewardName, just have a set of options (ie pre set choices for label) There are many ways you can do something but I would use the KISS approach first. Especially if its your first core data app.